# Indication of Gaussian integers solutions for $x^2+y^2=z^3$.

Tags: diophantine-equations, gaussian-integers

I know the existence of infinitely many integer solutions for $x^2+y^2=z^3$. But my concern is the existence of Gaussian Integers solution of this diophantine equation. I try to search for relevant papers but most discuss in terms of integer solutions only. Thank you.

Comment: We have $\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb Z[i]$, so integer solutions are also gaussian integer solutions. Also, if $(a,b,c)$ is an integer solution, $(ai,bi,-c)$ is also a solution. Are you asking for solutions whose entries have both real and imaginary part nonzero?

Comment: Over the Gaussian integers the LHS factors as $(x + iy)(x - iy)$ so you can write solutions down by setting $x + iy = a^3, x - iy = b^3$ (where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$), so that $x = \frac{a^3 + b^3}{2}, y = \frac{a^3 - b^3}{2i}$. Then you just need to pick $a, b$ such that $x, y$ have integer coefficients. This doesn't generate all solutions but it's not hard to generalize from here to figuring out all solutions using unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas okay, that is a good indication. Sure.. Do you reckon any solutions exist in the form of entries with both real and imaginary part nonzero? I really appreciate your replies.

Comment: @shahrinaismail: There are lots of solutions: one example is $(1-3i)^2+(1+2i)^2=(1+2i)^3$. Another is $(1-2i)^2+(1+3i)^2=(1-2i)^3$

Comment: I think Qiaochu's approach might be a viable one to find all gaussian integer solutions but I haven't worked it out completely.

Comment: There are formulas for parametrization of solutions. If you set parameters there as Gaussian numbers... then you can get solutions in the form of the same numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z^3=uv,\qquad z,u,v \in \Bbb{Z}[i]$$ then $$z^3=x^2+y^2, \qquad x = \frac{u+v}{2}, y = \frac{u-v}{2i}\in \frac12 \Bbb{Z}[i]$$

$x,y$ are in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ iff $u-v\in 2\Bbb{Z}[i]$ which implies that $u=v=z\bmod 2 \Bbb{Z}[i]$.

Every solution is of this form.

In particular there is no solution with $z=1+i$

and there is one iff $z\in 2\Bbb{Z}[i]$ or $1+2\Bbb{Z}[i]$.